# Use component declared in app module in another module

Tags: angular, angular-module

I have a Notification Popup declare in app module.
This Notification Popup is custom so it have custom fields marked as @Inputs. I want to be able to use this component in another component that requires notification popup functionality.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    TranslateModule.forChild(),
  ]
})
export class PopupNotificationModule { }
```

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PopupNotificationComponent 
  ],
  imports: [
    PopupNotificationModule
  ],

})

export class AppModule
```

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CarListComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
  ],

})

export class CarModule { }
```

I tried importing and exporting but without succes.

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get errors? How are you trying to use this component? In which Module is the component declared?

Comment: The page simply doesn't load, I tried multiple npm restarts

Answer (score 3):

first you have to add **PopupNotificationComponent** in declarations and export section of **PopupNotificationModule**  like that

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [PopupNotificationComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    TranslateModule.forChild(),
  ],
  exports: [PopupNotificationComponent],
})
export class PopupNotificationModule { }
```

then you have to import **PopupNotificationModule**  in **app module** import section like that

```
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        PopupNotificationModule,
        CarModule 
      ],
    
    })
    
    export class AppModule
```

now you have import **PopupNotificationModule**  in another module where you want to use **PopupNotificationComponent**

in your case it is **CarModule**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CarListComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    PopupNotificationModule 
  ],

})

export class CarModule { }
```

now you can use **PopupNotificationComponent** selector in **CarModule** components.

i hope this will work for you

Comment: Yes .. Exporting the Component in shared module was the thing I'm Missing

Comment: This was a good reminder for me today!

Answer (score 0):

Make a separate folder which includes notification-popup component and module file make module like

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [PopupNotificationComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    TranslateModule.forChild(),
  ]
})
export class PopupNotificationModule { }
```

Declare PopupNotificationComponent in PopupNotificationModule and whenever you wish to use in another module just import PopupNotificationModule and that's it.

Comment: I have the notification popup selector in app.component.html and console says: '1. If 'popup-notification' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.' but if declared: 'The Component 'PopupNotificationComponent' is declared by more than one NgModule.' (declared in notification module and app module)

Comment: In that case, do not put the component inside the `declaration` array in `AppModule`, but instead import the `PopupNotificationModule` inside `AppModule`. Plus, if the error keeps popping up, make sure to add the component in `exports` section of `PopupNotificationModule`.

Comment: Exports PopupNotificationComponent into PopupNotificationModule hope this will resolve your problem